# C++ generating a pascal triangle, wrong output

Tags: c++, pascals-triangle

I have a problem with generating a pascal triangle in c++, same algorithm works good in java and in c++ it only works for the first two numbers of every line of the triangle in any other it generates way to big numbers. For example in java it generates:
1 5 10 10 5 1 and in C++: 1 5 1233124 1241241585 32523523500 etc
Here is code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Pascal {
private:
    int* tab;
    int prev1;
    int prev2;
    public:

    Pascal(int n) {
        tab = new int[n+1];
        prev1=0;
        prev2=0;

        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for(int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                if (k == 0) {
                    tab[k] = 1;
                    prev2 = 1;
                } else {
                    prev1 = tab[k-1] + tab[k];
                    tab[k-1] = prev2;
                    prev2 = prev1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

int wspolczynnik(int m) {
    return tab[m];
  }
 };

 int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n = 0, m = 0;

n = atoi(argv[1]);  // konwersja string na int

if (n >= 0)

    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        Pascal *wiersz = new Pascal(n);
        m = atoi(argv[i]);


        int result = wiersz->wspolczynnik(m);

        if (m < 0 || m > n)
            cout << m << " - element poza zakresem" << endl;
        else
            cout << m << " : " << result << endl;

        delete[] wiersz;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The 'pascal' tag here refers to the programming language, not the triangle. Please read the description of tags before using them, to make sure you use tags that are actually relevant to your question. It helps them get to the people who can answer, and properly classifies them for use later in searches. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if initializing the `tab` array helps:

> tab = new int[n+1]();